# How to disprove : Vector division - sum of vectors dividing linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra, and want to know if there are two (or more) non-zero vectors, and their linear combination is also given.

Is it possible to disprove that their linear combination is divisible by the sum of individual vectors.

Also, if the vectors are just comprised of single constant terms, then will it make the case easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that by 'divisible by' you mean 'is a scalar multiple of'. Your conjecture is then that all linear combination of a set of vectors is a scalar multiple of their sum. You can see this is clearly false by considering vectors in the plane.

It is not clear what you mean by 'single constant terms'. If you mean the coefficients relative to some basis, for example the vector (1,0), then this is not relevant since any non-zero vector can be expressed in this extremely simple form relative to a basis of which  it is the first member.

Comment: Yes,  I meant by 'divisibility' a  scalar multiple only. But, sorry for being not so much talented so as to see on a graph paper, for even two vectors that their linear combination is divisible by the individual vectors. You can take me as novice. Then please tell me how to interpret diagrammatically the division of any linear combination (simplest possible being with both vectors just added/subtracted) being divided by the sum of individual vectors. I hope there is an algebraic interpretation to division, that I am not aware of, and not getting to know by reading any of the books available.